# Multiple Arrays - Insert Value into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, foreach

Currently working on a service script with a friend. When I say service script I mean it will only be used for updating and adding values to the database. Now my friend has stored all her soon to be values of the database as arrays.

I have already succeeded at entering in one of the arrays now I am confused on how I could do it for multiple arrays. So all in all this is more of a question on how I can refactor my 
current code to be more dynamic.

Also please keep in mind, she has hundreds of arrays that this needs to be done to so its not like 2 or 3 its literally hundreds.

My updated code : (please read the comments)

```
$colors['Colors_All'] = array("Black","Charcoal"); // Add unique indexes
$colors['Colors_Bright_All'] = array("Silver","White"); // Add unique indexes

$AllArrays = get_defined_vars(); // Get all defined vars
$Arrays = array(); // Set a default array

foreach ($AllArrays as $varName => $value) { // Run through all the variables set in AllArrays
        if(is_array($value) && $varName == 'colors') { // If array is colors then
                $Arrays = array_merge($Arrays, $value); // Merge those arrays into the new array
        }
}

var_dump($Arrays);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `product_features` ("; // Create the initial query

foreach ($Arrays as $column => $value) { // ForEach over the array
        $sql .= "$column,"; // Use the Key Example : 'Colors_All and Color_Bright_All' as a column name
}

$sql2 = rtrim($sql, ","); // trim the initial "," from the columns at the end
$sql2 .= ")"; // Close off the columns names
$sql2 .= " VALUES ";

foreach ($Arrays as $column => $value) { // This is where the problem starts -_-
        foreach ($value as $key => $insert) { // Get the value
                $sql2 .= "('$insert', '$insert'),"; // I need to have unique values here :(
        }
}

$finSQL = rtrim($sql2, ","); // Strip off the remaining ","
```

Also I know am not binding parameters, I will once I get the actual hard stuff out the way.

Now when doing a dump of $finSQL I get this :

```
string(152) "INSERT INTO `product_features` (Colors_All,Colors_Bright_All) VALUES ('Black', 'Black'),('Charcoal', 'Charcoal'),('Silver', 'Silver'),('White', 'White')"
```

How can I have the unique values be the VALUES in my insert query? That is the last part of this that is confusing me.

Comment: Do you have a lot of defined variables defined in the PHP script?  I wouldn't recommend it, but if they don't follow an explicit pattern, you could try using `get_defined_vars()`.  Are you able to show a bit more of your code?

Comment: Could you reword what you just typed? A pile of defined variables defined in the PHP doc? And I will take a look at get_defined_vars()

Comment: You seem to be lacking any sensible key to link the various colors together. It would help if you explained what the final database should look like.

Comment: There are no links between them sir. She states "I’m mainly fetching these columns to dynamically populate form elements (mostly <select> elements)"

Comment: Updated the code, almost 100% working just need help with inserting unique variables rather then the the same $input I am lost there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I got it "done" by serializing each array and using the actual array index as the unique identifier in the database like so :

```
<?php
ini_set("error_reporting", E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", TRUE);

$conn = new MysqlI("HOST", "USER", "PASSWORD", "DATABASE" /*Optionally put the PORT NUMBER HERE : , 3306 */);    
$conn->set_charset('utf8'); // Always explicitly state the character encoding!

$clearSQL = "TRUNCATE TABLE `product_features`;";
$clearNOW = $conn->prepare($clearSQL);// For updating this will delete all records in the table
$clearNOW->execute();

$colors['Colors_All'] = array("Black", "Charcoal", "Pink", "Cheese", "Dog", "Punk"); // Add unique indexes
$colors['Colors_Bright'] = array("Silver", "White", "Yellow", "Blue", "Indigo"); // Add unique indexes
$colors['Colors_Bright_All'] = array("Silver", "White", "DarkYellow", "Dark_Pink",); // Add unique indexes
$colors['Colors_Dark'] = array("Silver", "White", "DarkWE", "DarkCheese", "DarkBla"); // Add unique indexes
$colors['Colors'] = array("Silver", "White", "DarkIDK", "DarKsome", "waDark", "dark"); // Add unique indexes
$colors['Colors_Green'] = array("Silver", "White", "WAA", "WIWIW", "OMG", "Blood"); // Add unique indexes
$colors['Colors_Red'] = array("Silver", "White", "IRI", "owow", "Darkness", "night"); // Add unique indexes

$AllArrays = get_defined_vars(); // Get all defined vars
$Arrays = array(); // Set a default array

foreach ($AllArrays as $varName => $value) { // Run through all the variables set in AllArrays
    if (is_array($value) && $varName == 'colors') { // If array is colors then
       $Arrays = array_merge($Arrays, $value); // Merge those arrays into the new array
    }
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `product_features` (`ArrayIndex`, `ArrayValues`) VALUES "; // Create the initial query

foreach ($Arrays as $ArrayIndex => $Arrayvalues) { // ForEach over the array
     $sql .= "('$ArrayIndex','" . $mysqli->mysqli_real_escape_string(serialize($Arrayvalues)) . "'),"; // Use Array Index as the Unique Array Identifyer and Arrayvalues for the value
}

$finSQL = rtrim($sql, ","); // Strip off the remaining ","

var_dump($finSQL); // Check the query

$INSERT = $conn->prepare($finSQL); // Get query ready
$INSERT->execute(); // Execute

?>
```

And the result of that in the database is [this](http://puu.sh/2Ekaq.png)

Comment: all this stuff with `$AllArrays` being **totally useless.** You are getting **exactly the same `$colors` array** you have already. And storing serialized arrays in database makes no sense.

Comment: Who cares what makes sense to you? - Who are you? oO... this works, and I had success with it. I am only answering my answer since what you and what others said was absolutely useless. So please do something with your life. - Thanks.

Comment: If you have a better way to do it then please do tell. This was not my issue, I would never store arrays in a database, but I came across a problem a fellow SO member had and I tried to help. Unlike others

Answer (score 1):

Put $Colors_Bright_All, $Colors_Light_All into one final array lets say $finalArray and use foreach loop to loop through that array and then perform your existing foreach loop in that.

Comment: Right, but now I need those values to be inserted into different columns in a database based off their array name

Comment: if name = foo then insert into a else if name = yo then insert into b. Vola. You should be using separate arrays though.

Comment: Alright chandresh I might have come up with a solution but I have a question for you. How would I combine ~300 arrays without having to type them out? (yes literally around 300 arrays)

Comment: Updated the code, almost 100% working just need help with inserting unique variables rather then the the same $input I am lost there...

Answer (score 0):

As a solution to your above mentioned problem please try executing following code snippet

E.g.

```
    $finalarray=array();

    $Colors_Bright_All =    array("Silver","White","Gold","Royal_Blue","Dodger_Blue","Deep_Sky_Blue","Deep_Green","Forest_Green","Bright_Green","Violet"); 

   $Colors_Light_All = array("Light_Gray","Silver","White","Gold","Dodger_Blue","Deep_Sky_Blue","Light_Blue","Bright_Green","LightGreen","Light_Green");

 array_push($finalarray,'('.join(',',$Colors_Bright_All).')');
 array_push($finalarray,'('.join(',',$Colors_Light_All).')');

  $value=join(',',$finalarray);

 $sql = "INSERT INTO `product_features` (Colors_All) VALUES ".$value; // Build the initial query 
 $finSQL = rtrim($sql, ","); // Strip the last , so our mysql query doesn't goof up. 
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($finSQL);
 $stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've been told in other answers already, to make a nested array is the only sane way

```
$colors['bright'] = array("Silver","White","Gold"...); 
$colors['light']  = array("Light_Gray","Silver","White"...);

foreach ($colors as $type => $array) {

     // put your code here

}
```

if you need more data for insert beside just `$type` (as it cannot be told from your extremely vague question), you may add an array with this data as well

Comment: Didn't think this was vague... I have a piece of code now that works, I need that piece of code to add data from an array to a database dynamically. Sorry if that what is stumping every one.

Comment: `code to add data from an array to a database dynamically` - your code does it already. There are some other issues you face but still keep hiding from people.

Comment: Hiding it? :S I'm lost I'm sorry if you think that way. I thought when I wrote up this question it was well written and to the point :S

Comment: Updated the code, almost 100% working just need help with inserting unique variables rather then the the same $input I am lost there...

Answer (score 0):

if your code works fine, then change

```
foreach ($Arrays as $column => $value) { // This is where the problem starts -_-
        foreach ($value as $key => $insert) { // Get the value
                $sql2 .= "('$insert', '$insert'),"; // I need to have unique values here :(
        }
}
```

to

```
foreach ($Arrays as $column => $value) { // The problem will be fixed :D
        $sql2 .="(";
        foreach ($value as $key => $insert) { // Get the value
                $sql2 .= "'$insert',"; // You will have unique values here :D
        }
        $sql2 = chop($sql2,","); // strip the ending ,
        $sql2 .= "),";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
function myInsert($myArray)
{
    $colour_value = "";
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `product_features` (Colors_All) VALUES (?)");

    if ($stmt) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $colour_value );


        foreach ($myArrayas AS $value) {
            $colour_value = $value;
            $stmt->execute();
        }

        $stmt->close();
    }
}


function myInsert($Colors_Bright_All);
function myInsert($Colors_Light_All);
?>
```

EDIT

```
<?php
$newArray = array();

foreach( $_GLOBALS as $val )
{
    if( substr($val, 0, 7) == "Colors_" )
        myInsert($val);
}

?>
```

Comment: so a function for 100 + arrays... yea... no.. what you just did I already have?

Comment: My text was missing.. Yeah I know they are the similar, you were only using your using prepared statement partially. In your question you don't state where you get the arrays from. You would just call the function in a loop with each array.

Comment: To have 100+ arrays I'd have to assume from a database? Or are they hard coded? you just use foreach($result as $data) myInsert($data);

Comment: She typed out all the array values by hand. Now she doesn't want to have to enter in 300+ arrays into a database which each array probably has 20 - 30 values in it... and yea I was using PDO incorrectly but on purpose.

Comment: @RixhersAjazi that should pick up all your arrays

Comment: As per your comment to another answer, to insert another field by name: $array_name = substr($val, 7); Should return the "Bright_All" part of the name.